# QBWC1041: SendRequestXML failed due to error message

Tags: php, magento, quickbooks

i was getting "QBWC1041: SendRequestXML failed due to error message" in web connector when i checked in the consolibytes site i found this

http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_-_SendRequestXML_failed

and i checked the php error log file and i getting the following error

```
   [25-Apr-2014 04:41:15 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/wholecab/public_html/store/qbsdkm/QuickBooks/Driver/.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/wholecab/public_html/store/qbsdkm') in /home/wholecab/public_html/store/qbsdkm/QuickBooks/Loader.php on line 56
```

why i was getting this error?

here is the code 
config.php

```
    <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')){  
            date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
        }

        require_once '../QuickBooks.php';

        $user = 'quickbooks';
        $pass = 'password';

        // Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
        $map = array(
            QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_query_request', '_quickbooks_customer_query_response', '_quickbooks_error_handler' ),
            QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
            QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE => array( '_quickbooks_invoice_add_request', '_quickbooks_invoice_add_response' ),
            QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER => array( '_quickbooks_salesorder_add_request', '_quickbooks_salesorder_add_response' ),
            );  


        $errmap = array(
                    3070 =>  '_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong',
                    3140 => '_quickbooks_reference_error',
                    '*' => '_quickbooks_error_handler',
                );

        $hooks = array();
        $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;
        $soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;        
        $soap_options = array();
        $handler_options = array(
                    'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
                    'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
                );      
        $soap_options = array();
        $driver_options = array();
        $callback_options = array();


        $dsn = 'mysql://wholecab_user3:Sehar123#@localhost/wholecab_clickdb3';

        QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::initialize($dsn);  

        if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn)){
            // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
            QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);

            // This creates a username and password which is used by the Web Connector to authenticate
            QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);   
        }

        // Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
        // __construct($dsn_or_conn, $map, $errmap = array(), $hooks = array(), $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()
        $Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
        $response = $Server->handle(true, true);

        function _quickbooks_salesorder_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale){
            // We're just testing, so we'll just use a static test request:
            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="5.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                        <SalesOrderAddRq requestID="'.$requestID.'">
                            <SalesOrderAdd>
                                <CustomerRef>
                                    <FullName>Muralidhar, LLC (1249573828)</FullName>
                                </CustomerRef>
                                <TxnDate>2014-04-25</TxnDate>
                                <RefNumber>23112628110</RefNumber>
                                <BillAddress>
                                    <Addr1>Pam  Barker</Addr1>
                                    <Addr2>500 Kirts Boulevard</Addr2>
                                    <Addr3/>
                                    <City>Troy</City>
                                    <State>Mi</State>
                                    <PostalCode>48084</PostalCode>
                                    <Country>US</Country>
                                </BillAddress>
                                <ShipAddress>
                                    <Addr1/>
                                    <Addr2>7322 Southwest Freeway</Addr2>
                                    <Addr3>Ste, 170</Addr3>
                                    <City>Houston</City>
                                    <State>TX</State>
                                    <PostalCode>77074</PostalCode>
                                    <Country>US</Country>
                                </ShipAddress>                      
                                <Memo>Shipping to Pinnacle Senior Care Houston</Memo>
                                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                    <ItemRef>
                                        <FullName>ARCTIC WHITE SHAKER:AWS-1530MD</FullName>
                                    </ItemRef>
                                    <Desc>MULLION DOOR FOR W1530 - ARCTIC WHITE SHAKER</Desc>
                                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                                    <Amount>59.25</Amount>
                                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                    <ItemRef>
                                        <FullName>ARCTIC WHITE SHAKER:AWS-1536MD</FullName>
                                    </ItemRef>
                                    <Desc>MULLION DOOR FOR W1536 - ARCTIC WHITE SHAKER</Desc>
                                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                                    <Amount>59.25</Amount>
                                </SalesOrderLineAdd>                        
                            </SalesOrderAdd>
                        </SalesOrderAddRq>
                    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>';

            return $xml;
        }

        function _quickbooks_salesorder_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents){
            $content = "##########################################################";
            $content .= $idents;
            $content .= "##########################################################";
            $content .= $xml;
            $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/store/qbsdkm/docs/myText.txt","wb");
            fwrite($fp,$content);
            fclose($fp);
            return; 
        }

        function _quickbooks_invoice_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale){
            // We're just testing, so we'll just use a static test request:
            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="5.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <InvoiceAddRq requestID="'.$requestID.'">
                      <InvoiceAdd>
                        <CustomerRef>
                          <FullName>Muralidhar, LLC (1249573828)</FullName>
                        </CustomerRef>
                        <TxnDate>2014-04-23</TxnDate>
                        <RefNumber>9668</RefNumber>
                        <BillAddress>
                          <Addr1>56 Cowles Road</Addr1>
                          <City>Willington</City>
                          <State>CT</State>
                          <PostalCode>06279</PostalCode>
                          <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <PONumber></PONumber>
                        <Memo></Memo>

                        <InvoiceLineAdd>
                          <ItemRef>
                            <FullName>Test Item</FullName>
                          </ItemRef>
                          <Desc>Item 1 Description Goes Here</Desc>
                          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                          <Rate>295</Rate>
                        </InvoiceLineAdd>

                        <InvoiceLineAdd>
                          <ItemRef>
                            <FullName>Test Item</FullName>
                          </ItemRef>
                          <Desc>Item 2 Description Goes Here</Desc>
                          <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                          <Rate>25</Rate>
                        </InvoiceLineAdd>

                      </InvoiceAdd>
                    </InvoiceAddRq>
                  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>';

            return $xml;
        }

        function _quickbooks_invoice_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents){
            $content = "##########################################################";
            $content .= $idents;
            $content .= "##########################################################";
            $content .= $xml;
            $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/store/qbsdkm/docs/myText.txt","wb");
            fwrite($fp,$content);
            fclose($fp);
            return; 
        }

        function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale){
            // We're just testing, so we'll just use a static test request:  
            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="5.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                        <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                            <CustomerAdd>
                                <Name>Muralidhar, LLC (' . mt_rand() . ')</Name>
                                <CompanyName>Muralidhar, LLC</CompanyName>
                                <FirstName>Murali</FirstName>
                                <LastName>Developer</LastName>
                                <BillAddress>
                                    <Addr1>Muralidhar, LLC</Addr1>
                                    <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                                    <City>NewYork</City>
                                    <State>NY</State>
                                    <PostalCode>10001</PostalCode>
                                    <Country>United States</Country>
                                </BillAddress>
                                <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
                                <AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>
                                <Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>
                                <Email>Murali@Muralidhar.com</Email>
                                <Contact>Murali Developer</Contact>
                            </CustomerAdd>
                        </CustomerAddRq>
                    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>';

            return $xml;
        }

        /**
         * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
         */
        function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents){
            $content = $xml;
            $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/store/qbsdkm/docs/myText.txt","wb");
            fwrite($fp,$content);
            fclose($fp);
            return; 
        }

        function _quickbooks_customer_query_request($requestID , $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale){
            /*$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="5.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
                    <CustomerQueryRq>
                      <MaxReturned>5</MaxReturned>
                      <FromModifiedDate>1984-01-29T22:03:19</FromModifiedDate>
                      <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                    </CustomerQueryRq>
                  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>';*/
                $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                        <?qbxml version="5.0"?>
                        <QBXML>
                            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
                                <CustomerQueryRq requestID="' . $requestID . '" iterator="Start">
                                    <MaxReturned>10</MaxReturned>
                                    <FromModifiedDate>1984-01-29T22:03:19</FromModifiedDate>
                                    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                                </CustomerQueryRq>
                            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                        </QBXML>';
            return $xml;
        }

        function _quickbooks_customer_query_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents){ 
            $content = $xml;
            $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/store/qbsdkm/docs/myText.txt","wb");
            fwrite($fp,$content);
            fclose($fp);
        }

        function _quickbooks_error_handler($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg){
            $content = "##########################################################";
            $content .= $idents;
            $content .= "##########################################################";
            $content .= $xml;
            $content .= "##########################################################";
            $content .= $errmsg;
            $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/store/qbsdkm/docs/myText.txt","a");
            fwrite($fp,$content);
            fclose($fp);
        }

        function _quickbooks_reference_error($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg){
            $content = "##########################################################";
            $content .= $idents;
            $content .= "##########################################################";
            $content .= $xml;
            $content .= "##########################################################";
            $content .= $errmsg;
            $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/store/qbsdkm/docs/myText.txt","a");
            fwrite($fp,$content);
            fclose($fp);
        }
```

and the other file wholeqb.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();

    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, mt_rand());
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER,mt_rand());
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER, mt_rand());
```

Thanks,

Murali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>$10 says that you have a $dsn variable that's empty in your code.</strike>

But you didn't post your code, so it's hard to say for sure. Post your code?

Updated answer now that you've posted your code -

In your `wholeqb.php` file, you need to either initialize the singleton first:

`QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::initialize($dsn);`

Or just create the object instead of using a singleton:

`$Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);`

Make sure you set the $dsn variable *in the wholeqb.php file* to a valid SQL connection string too.

Comment: Hi Keith, 

Thanks for the reply i updated my question with the code please check it
and one more question in the your example the there was example to import the orders,products,customer from the quickbook to mysql db / site 

        docs/example_web_connector_import.php

like that is there any example to import orders,customer from magento site to quickbook desktop edition
pleae help me on this 

Thanks,
Murali.